# Branch.io passing Google Campaign code?

Tags: branch.io

I am using branch.io for deferred deep linking with a google ad campaign. I am [following branch instructions](https://dev.branch.io/features/google-uac/guide/).

The links is formatted like this:

```html
http://branch.io?adid={adid}&lat={lat}&click_url={click_url}&link_identifier=<myspecificlinkidentifier>
```

The assumption seems to be a different branch links will be created for each campaign.  In order to simplify management I would like to just pass the [campaign code through from google](https://developers.google.com/app-conversion-tracking/ios/confirm) {campaign_id}.

Or really any parameter as long is it will come back through when my app requests link data.

(I am using this to be able to understand how users behave when broken down by  how they arrived to the system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run ads with different campaign codes you will need to create separate links and set the required metadata parameters during link creation. It is not possible to pass anything other than the link ID (the value after link_identifier) back to Branch from a Google Universal App Campaign.

This information comes directly from the Branch product manager who designed this integration.